# Should Dalvik Cache be wiped in the case of switching Lollipop ROMs

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom, dalvik

I know what dalvik and ART is.

But my question is, when switching custom ROMs (All anything above 5.0), **is it necessary to wipe the dalvik cache?** Wiping the Cache is necessary but wiping dalvik (which doesnt exist in Lollipop) should be necessary or not. What impact will it cause if we wipe dalvik (something not present).

In lollipop, What does the **dalvik** cache contain(is it an empty folder?)

Comment: It's not even necessary most of the time anyways. Likely this depends on your recovery and device...I would treat it as undefined behavior and avoid it.

Comment: What does the dalvik cache contain in a Lollipop ROM?

Comment: It's just the old folder structure, it holds nothing and it should be empty (as you say it is). Clear Dalvik Cache is always there on custom ROMs, partly for historical reasons, but now what they are calling the ART cache is cleared by some of the newer recoveries (I'm not sure how, or if this works), and some have the word 'Dalvik' still in place as they either forgot or didn't bother to update the wording.

Comment: So that means its an empty folder? Hence clearing an empty folder doesn't make a difference... So clearing the dalvik in a lollipop doesn't make a difference. Am I right? Is there some source where I can make sure it works this way ...

Comment: Related: [Should Dalvik Cache be wiped in ART](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/111525/16575)