# Should Dalvik Cache be wiped in Android OS that supports ART?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, dalvik, art

When switching custom ROMs (in ART), is it necessary to wipe the Dalvik Cache?

Wiping the Cache is necessary, but should wiping Dalvik (which doesn't exist in Android Lollipop and afterward) be necessary?

What impact will it cause if we wipe Dalvik (something not present)?

In ART, what does the Dalvik cache contains? (is it an empty folder?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dalvik Cache is still in use under ART, it is the location where the .oat files (they contain the compiled application, compiled during installation ) are stored, they just didn't change the name. Source: [1](http://bofh.nikhef.nl/events/HitB/hitb-2014-amsterdam/praatjes/D1T2-State-of-the-Art-Exploring-the-New-Android-KitKat-Runtime.pdf)

So Wiping may be necessary if ART related files were updated. Because it does no harm other than compiling all applications again, I suggest just doing it to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to wipe it. It is probably still in recoveries because you could need it at some point, or developers just didn't remove it yet.

For me, dalvik cache folder is empty.

Comment: Sounds correct to me (+1) – but who tells us that the corresponding menu doesn't figure that and cares for ART as well? [Quote](https://sourcex.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/art-runtime-for-kitkat-4-4-explained/): *So, for using the ART cache the custom recovery(like CWM ,TWPR ) will need to optimise it to clear the ART Cache also (if only ART is default Runtime)* That article being from 11/2013, I could imagine new versions of CWM/TWRP might cover that.

Comment: PS: Like the Dalvik cache being in `/data/dalvik-cache`, ART Cache is stored in `/data/art-cache`. And according to [this post](http://www.android-hilfe.de/8449823-post278.html) (quoted instructions are in English), it's exactly as I assumed: *WIPE Dalvik/ART Cache (wipe cache partition + wipe dalvik cache)*. Even seems like Philz recovery has renamed the item already to "WIPE DALVIK/ART CACHE".

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best that you wipe it because it is still where the compiled oat files are stored and either way all it does is make the system recompile all the apps. You still have to wait a long time while it does the compiling (Android is Upgrading)