# Android continues rebooting and 'optimizing'

Tags: updates, rom

My S5 was running Fusion ROM 5.0.   I downloaded 5.1 and installed using ROM manager.  After the installation, Android continues rebooting and saying "Optimizing app 1 of 8.   Facebook...", then reboots a few seconds later into the same process.

What do I do to break this cycle and get my phone back?

Answer (score 1):

It may be problem by the rom

- clear the data
- clear dalvik  cache
- reinstall ROM

This may help cause you may have directly the ROM without clearing data

---

Footnote: Though in Android 5, Dalvik was replaced by ART, parts of the Dalvik stuff are still used (`/data/dalvik-cache/arm/*`; also see e.g. [Should Dalvik Cache be wiped in ART](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/111525/16575)). While in the end, apps will run from native Elf binaries, ART creates those via `.oat` files. Details can be found e.g. in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime). So don't be confused about "clearing Dalvik cache" here. You could still make sure to remove ART cache by running `rm -rf /data/dalvik-cache/arm/*` as root via e.g. `adb shell` when in recovery.

Comment: I fixed by trashing Fusion which was previously installed (the upgrade broke shit).   Using Cyanogenmod  now, no problems installing.

Comment: Actually this happens when you use old ROM and don't clear the data